# Confirm AWS Cognito user without email or phone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, verification

I made an AWS Cognito user pool without email or phone attributes (only username and password) and MFA turned off. When a new user signs up, however, they are unable to login until their account has been confirmed. Of course, this is not possible because of the lack of email or phone to send a verification code to.

How can I either not require user confirmation, or automatically confirm users upon sign up?

Here's some screenshots of the relevant tabs from the Cognito user pool:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/signing-up-users-in-your-app.html

If you choose this option, Amazon Cognito doesn't send verification codes when users sign up. Choose this option if you are using a custom authentication flow that verifies at least one contact method without using verification codes from Amazon Cognito. For example, you might use a pre sign-up Lambda trigger that automatically verifies email addresses that belong to a specific domain.

Answer (score 3):

You can confirm your users just after they are registered. To do this you will need to create a Lambda Function and [associate this function to your User Pool Pre Sign-up Lambda Trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-triggers.html).

Here is an example of a function that does exactly that using NodeJs runtime (Typescript):

```
import { Callback, Context } from 'aws-lambda';

export function handler(event: any, context: Context, callback: Callback): void {

    event.response.autoConfirmUser = true;
    event.response.autoVerifyEmail = true;
    callback(null, event);

}
```